# Run Time Error '1004' Unable to get PivotFields property of the PivotTable class

Tags: excel, vba

I developed a macro which generates automatically reports but with a certain type of data i'm receiving the error. I tried several things and i didn't managed to solve it so I'm asking for a bit of help. , This is the problematic line: `Fin = .PivotTables(1).PivotFields("Account Owner").VisibleItems.Count` and this is the full code:

```
Sub Generar_informes()

Dim i As Double
Dim Ini As Double
Dim Fin As Double

'Desactivamos actualización de pantalla
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Sheets("Pivot Table").Select
With Sheets("Pivot Table")

'indicamos la fila siguiente a la primera fila con datos
Ini = Columns(1).Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
'Contamos los todas los comerciales de la tabla dinámica1
Fin = .PivotTables(1).PivotFields("Account Owner").VisibleItems.Count

'Inciamos un bucle donde por cada comercial generamos informe
For i = 1 To Fin
'para mostrar el informe debemos hacer referencia a los campos de valores
.Cells(i + Ini, 2).ShowDetail = True
'Nombramos la pestaña con el nombre del comercial.
ActiveSheet.Name = .Cells(i + Ini, 1).Value
'Seleccionamos la hoja con el detalle del comercial
ActiveSheet.Select
'Movemos la hoja a un libro nuevo
ActiveSheet.Move
'Cambiamos color de celdas a modificar por los comerciales
Range("L1:N1").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 153, 0)
'Agregamos la lista desplegable
    Columns("N:N").Select
    With Selection.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:="Director,Manager,Owner,Staff,Top Executive(Chairman-Chief-etc),Vice President/SVP/EVP"
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With



ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ActiveSheet.Name

ActiveWorkbook.Close False
Next i
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox "¡Reportes generados exitosamente!"
End Sub
```

Thank you in advanced

Comment: What's the error you are getting?

Comment: Run Time Error '1004' Unable to get PivotFields property of the PivotTable class

Comment: That means the pivot table you are referring to doesn't have a field by that name.

Comment: But the problem is that it does: I named the pivot column. Account owner and that is what I'm refering to in the code

Comment: Do you have more than one Pivot-Table? If so `.PivotTables(1)` could reference the wrong table.

Comment: I tried this but also doesn't work, I just have 1 Pivot table

Comment: I suggest you double check that with something like: `for each pf in .pivottables(1).pivotfields: debug.print chr(34) & pf.name & chr(34): next` The quotes are there so you'll be able to see any leading or trailing spaces.

Comment: With this command the error don't occur so I guess is double checked.